# Validate email address format in .NET without exceptions

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I'm using this code:

```
    public static bool IsEmailAddress(this string value)
    {
        try
        {
            new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(value);
            return true;
        }
        catch ()
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to do this without using exceptions?

Comment: There is no public built-in API for that; sorry.

Comment: Use a regular expression, that would be the easiest way.

Comment: Sigh. I opened a bug report. Please up-vote: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25295

Comment: Meh, you can write your own `TryParse` extension, would be super simple.

Comment: @Igor That's silly. To do it with RegEx would take even more code than this and it would be less accurate.

Comment: @DavidG That's what I'm dong now. But there are performance and debugging implications with unnecessarily throwing and catching exceptions. (Though later versions of VS make the debugging somewhat less painful.)

Comment: Validation by exception is nasty though, RegEx is pretty simple and really not a lot of code.

Comment: In general catching all exceptions should be avoided, and it’s best practice to only catch exceptions you expect. In this case here you should restrict it to FormatException and maybe ArgumentException if you want to handle empty and null mail addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression.

```
private const string EmailRegularExpression = @"^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$";
private static Regex EmailValidRegex = new Regex(CommonValues.EmailRegularExpression, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

public static bool IsEmailValid(string emailAddress)
{
    return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emailAddress) && EmailValidRegex.IsMatch(emailAddress);
}
```

See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html which is where I snagged the expression from.